# Discount from Specific Shipping Method based on coupon code in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon-codes

I need in admin section to apply coupon only on particular shipping method not discount from other shipping method. I should be able to select shipping method in admin which I want to allow for discount.

In frontend whenever customer apply that coupon, the amount should not deducted from the subtotal/ grand total, Only the particular shipping method(Which we had allowed in admin section) should be pre-selected and shown with discount applied.

Please find the sample screenshot in attachment. This is what I want to achieve.

[image: Frontend Checkout page]

[image: Coupon Code]

[image: Admin Section]

Comment: are you using this module https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/shipping-discount-1.html ?

Comment: No, I checked this module but it's rating is low and it have different functionality. @paj

Comment: So how are you implementing this discount? Have you developed your own module and code?

Comment: I want to create my own module because there is no paid or free extension available for this. Do you have nay idea how to implement this? @paj

Comment: I can create such extension for you but it will be paid

Comment: @BornCoder: Please note ahsan.horani@gmail.com